# PHP Variable in mysql call $sql( SELECT * FROM Example WHERE Example = "$example" )

Tags: php, mysql, local-storage

I have a form that allows people to add Soldiers to the list which is transferred to mysql just fine. It's even fine if I do it without a variable but once I try and added one like below.

```
// Get Variable from LocalStorage (This has been tested and does indeed return fine)
$affiliation = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('join_affiliation'));</script>";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation="'. $affiliation.'"';
```

It doesn't want to work. This code is used display's a table of all Affiliation related Soliders on the review page. I'm at a complete lost and not sure what to do at this point. I hope someone out there can help me out. Below is the full list of PHP code.

```
$affiliation = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('join_affiliation'));</script>";

// REMOVED USER AND PASSWORD OF COURSE :D
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
if (!con){ die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error()); } 


mysql_select_db("grainger_2013", $con);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation="'$affiliation'"';
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);

// ECHO TABLE CONTENTS      
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Side'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Role'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

// TEST VARIABLE (Does work)
echo '<p>' . $affiliation . '</p>';

mysql_close($con);
```

---

WORKS...

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = "TEST"';
```

DOESN'T WORK...

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = "' $affiliation '"';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = "' . $affiliation . '"';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($affiliation) . '"';

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation= '%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($affiliation));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation LIKE \"$affiliation\"";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = \"$affiliation \"";
```

Comment: `"It doesn't want to work."` is not a valid question. What is your expected result, and what is the result that you're currently obtaining?

Comment: $affiliation is a string of js so um er is it really what's in your db?

Comment: It would possibly work fine if you’d use the same code with string concatenation in `$sql`. And you should also properly escape the string in MySQL.

Comment: I just updated it. Basically I need it to grab the current Affiliation from the Database and display a table of all related soliders. The variable is pulling the Affiliation from Localstorage and I need it to be used in the ( WHERE Affiliation = "HERE" ) call. But it returns empty without errors and once I insert a static variable it works.

Comment: Gumbo - I have used the escape string before and nothing changed.

Comment: Dagon - Affiliation is included in the table to help separate the Soldiers. $affiliation is used to pull a variable from Localstorage.

Comment: You cannot access localstorage via PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is wrong, you are mixing concepts:

- Server side: PHP, MySQL
- Client side: HTML, CSS, JS

PHP cannot interact with the browser in this way, the flow is as follows:

1. The browser sends a request to the server to see a page
2. The server passes some information to PHP
3. PHP does its stuff and generates text as output (HTML generally)
4. The text is interpreted by the browser as HTML to render the page, and maybe CSS and JS
5. The browser executes the JS code and does whatever stuff it means to do
6. Repeat

You need to structure your code with this in mind: does the browser needs to do `X` before PHP can do `Y`? then PHP should check `if (browser did X) { ... do Y ... } else { tell browser "Do X" }`.

If the browser is doing `X` and needs information from the server, maybe loading a new URL with *a query* will retrieve that information, obviously you'd need a new PHP script to *answer* that query.

### Second part

Divide your logic into steps:

1. Prepare the information you need from the DB, use PHP to build the HTML and add some JS values if needed, send the page to the browser
2. Allow the browser to determine what information will need next, send async [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) requests if the user should not leave the current page but the browser needs further DB infmration
3. Prepare a new PHP script to answer the AJAX request, verify what's needed, return the information with [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) if possible ([`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) to simplify the process at the browser
4. Still at browser, the JS will receive the AJAX response, parse it, and take some actions
5. Depending of the logic of your app/script, you may need to prepare more information to be sent at the server again, based on user actions

#### Implementing your idea

There are different strategies to achieve what you want to do, some might be easy, some might be hard, the one you choose will depend in how it fits with the rest of your code or idea.

From your description:

- The browser has a value stored
- PHP needs said value
- DB will retrieve a list of matches
- The browser will show these matches

So:

1. The user needs to visit the page first, at this point the page has no `Reenactors` list show anywhere, but it can show a message stating that it is processing the list
2. Once the page loads, a small script retrieves the `join_affiliation` value and sends the AJAX request to some script like `reenactors.php?affiliation=<join_affiliation>`
3. User sees a spinning wheel meanwhile
4. AJAX request returns:

   - error: message to user "No reenactors found for affiliation "
   - success: create the list, or add the list (depends on the response of the PHP script)

**Important**: `mysql_*` family of functions has been deprecated, its use is discouraged, as its low level control allowed malicious queries to be executed easily from code of inexpert coders. Using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) is recommended.

#### Reenactors list:

```
/**
 * By now, assume no errors when connecting to the DB
 */
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>','<USERNAME>','PASSWORD');
$affiliation = '<any>';

if (isset($_GET['affiliation'])) {
    $affiliation = $_GET['affiliation'];

    /**
     * Dynamic values are indicated by the question mark
     * Named variables are also possible:
     * http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
     *
     * No quotes around the placeholder of the string
     */
    $statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation=?');
    $statement->bindValue(1,$affiliation);
}
else {
    $statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Reenactors');
}

/**
 * The query statement is ready, but hasn't executed yet
 * Retrieve/fetch all results once executed
 * http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
 *
 * Some prefer to read row by row using fetch()
 * Use it if the script starts to use too much memory
 */
$statement->execute();
$reenactors = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


/**
 * Display the affiliation, as part of the table
 * Assume the table will have 5 columns
 */
?>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Affiliation: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($affiliation) ?></th>
    </tr>
<?php

/**
 * Display the list
 * Assume the text can contain HTML and escape it
 * http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
 */
foreach ($reenactors as $reenactor) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($reenactor['ID']) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($reenactor['Side']) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($reenactor['Role']) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($reenactor['First_Name']) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($reenactor['Last_Name']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }

/**
 * What if, for some reason, the list is empty?
 */
if (!count($reenactors)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            This list is empty
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

#### Show list of reenactors dynamically (assumes use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/))

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reenactors of Historic Place Historic Event</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    /**
     * Wait until the document is ready
     */
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /**
         * Be warned, not all the browsers support localStorage
         * This line might cause an error at those browsers
         */
        var affiliation = localStorage.getItem('join_affiliation') || '';

        /**
         * jQuery.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
         * affiliation needs to be encoded to be added to the URL
         *
         * The request will start at this moment, and finish at an
         * undefined moment in the future
         *
         * success or error function will execute at that moment
         */
        $.ajax({
            url: 'reenactors.php?affiliation=' + encodeURIComponent(affiliation),
            error: function(){
                /**
                 * In case of error, find the table and show a message
                 */
                $('#reenactors-list td').text('There was a problem generating the list, please try later');
            },
            success: function(data_from_server){
                /**
                 * data_from_server will contain the list generated by the script
                 */
                $('#reenactors-list tbody').html(data_from_server);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Reenactors</h1>
    <table id="reenactors-list">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    The list of reenactors is loading, please wait... [spinning image here]
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I've been under the impression but I was able to access the localstorage file with PHP just fine so I was planning to use it. But I'm not sure how to go about this. I need to check what the Affiliation was that was entered in order to display a table of the soldiers. It's dynamic and would (seems like it would) be a lot of work that I don't have the experience to do.

Answer (score -1):

Change to this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation='". $affiliation."'";
```

Comment: you should use mysql_real_escape_string when placing variable in sql query

Comment: yes, correct. If you want to use mysql_real_escape_string(), $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation= '%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($affiliation));

Comment: Note the top code section. I have tried this before and still nothing :\

Comment: @Z33GHOST did you try to use mysql_real_escape_string yet?

Comment: Still doesn't work... $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($affiliation) . '"';

Comment: use like that $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation= '%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($affiliation));

Comment: Is there any output of $affiliation?

Comment: wont work, cant work, You cannot access localstorage via PHP.

Comment: This outputs fine (Use this to test: echo '<p>' . $affiliation . '</p>';)... <?php $affiliation = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('join_affiliation'));</script>"; ?>

Comment: @Z33GHOST just google it, every link will same the same thing.

Comment: I've been googling all day and can't seem to find a fix. This is my last resort.

Comment: Hay, I want exactly know $affiliation result. If there value is null or something? Another thing is directly print to $query. Then, copy all query and run directly at phpmyadmin or mysqlWorkB

Comment: Currently I've been using "Apple Co" for a test since it's got a space to it which would be common. Which when I remove the $affiliation and use that it works flawlessly. But the problem is it's not dynamic any more.

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation LIKE \"$affiliation\"";
```

Comment: Just made some changes,could you please try them?

Comment: Didn't work either *bangs head on desk* I think this is a 1D10T error XD

Comment: ok just to debug this thing,                                          echo"$affiliation";                                                   $sql = $sql = "SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation LIKE \"$affiliation\"";                                                     echo "$sql";                                                     This should give you a good idea where we are goofing up.

Comment: This is all I get for a error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /FILELOCATION/ on line 163. 163 is while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){ *echo tables code* }

Comment: Noo,I mean comment out all the PHP stuff for using the result from the DB.keep only these 3 lines.check the output of the 3rd thing to see if it works in the exact form in phpmyadmin

Comment: Scratch that I don't get that error anymore when it's listed as such (watch the quotes): $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = "' . $affiliation . '"';    Not like this: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Reenactors WHERE Affiliation = '" . $affiliation . "'";

Comment: So does it retrieve the values from the DB?

Comment: Do you mean only the $con = mysql_connect("localhost","X","X");
&... if (!con){ die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error()); }

Comment: No thats for the DB connection,we were testing the query part

Comment: If I remove...  WHERE Affiliation = "' . $affiliation . '" ...it does return the values just fine. But it needs to be Dynamic depending on what the user just submitted as their Affiliation.

Comment: So thats the problem,That is why I suggested to test the 3 things.Most probably the query is not being properly formed,thats messing it up.If we are able to see where the problem is it would be very easy to correct it.Right?

Comment: Any way you could dig into it or give me some test to run? Like I said I'm not great at PHP and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Could you please provide 1 row of dummy data?

Comment: Affiliation: Apple Co / First_Name: Thomas / Last_Name: Daugherty / Side: USA / Role: Artillery

Comment: Well as a little chuckle my girl just noticed I wrote $example. You'll crap bricks when you see it.

Comment: Hey,I just tested it.works either way for me. The thing that you were trying,the second line in the DOESN'T work section,make sure there are no spaces = "'.$affiliation.'"';Let me know,i will drop my test script if it still doesnt.

Comment: So far I still have the error. It's late here and I need some rest and return to it with fresh eyes. I have to return in the morning. Thanks everyone!